# sequence and measurable set

Tags: real-analysis

Please is the following assertion true?

Let $\tau\subset\mathbb{R}_+=[0,\infty)$ be a measurable set (the standard Lebesgue measure), $\mu(\mathbb{R}_+\backslash \tau)=0$.

Then there exists an increasing sequence $\{x_i\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\subset \tau,\quad x_i\to\infty$ such that for any $k,i,\quad k>i$ one has $x_k-x_i\in \tau$

i have no idea how to prove that

Comment: Can you see the intuition for the proof?

Comment: If $\mu(\mathbb{R}_{+}\setminus \tau)=0$, what happens with those elements such that $x_k - x_i \not\in \tau$?